# Command button code to replace special characters

Tags: excel, button, command, excel-2007, vba

I do not have any training in VB and I am simply using what I can find online to modify my code.

I have below code (pardon it if redundant) for an ActiveX command button that allows me to draw values from specific cells in my Excel spreadsheet (MS Office 2007) and uses these values as part of the file name to save it in a specified folder. However, some of the cells have characters that are not allowed in file names (e.g. /:*?"<>|).

How can I modify below code to replace such forbidden characters with a dash ("-")?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim FileName2 As String
    Dim FileName3 As String
    Dim FileName4 As String
    Dim FileName5 As String
    Dim FileName6 As String
    Dim FileName7 As String
    Dim str As String, strLeft As String
    str = Range("O7")
    strLeft = Left(str, 9)
    FileName1 = strLeft
    FileName2 = Range("Q7")
    FileName3 = Range("W7")
    FileName4 = Range("A7")
    FileName5 = Range("I7")
    FileName6 = Range("D7")
    FileName7 = Range("E7")
    Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\CURRENT PROJECTS\CatchAll\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & FileName1 & "_" & FileName2 & "_" &
    FileName3 & "_" & FileName4 & "_" & FileName5 & "_" & FileName6 & "_" &
    FileName7 & "_" & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all the characters with a "-" might be a bad idea. You may end up with a very long file name.

I use this simple function to clean any string to get a proper filename. Hope this helps you?

```
Function strClean(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "[\[\]|\/\\:\*\?""<>]"
        .Global = True
        strClean = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Siddarth. That worked too but the file name needed the "-" for a purpose. Besides, the denied characters were far and few in between. Thanks for a great suggestion again. Will keep it for other purposes.

Comment: If you need the "-" then change `vbNullString` to `"-"`. As simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe building a function to replace the unwanted characters:

```
Function RepCh(str As String)

myarray = Array("/", ":", "*", "?", Chr(34), "<", ">", "|")

For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    If i = LBound(myarray) Then
        NewStr = Replace(str, myarray(i), "-")
    Else
        NewStr = Replace(NewStr, myarray(i), "-")
    End If
Next i
RepCh = NewStr
End Function
```

then your string variables would be

```
Filename2 = RepCh(Range("Q7").value) ' or RepCh(cstr(Range("Q7").value))
```

but i don't know all the denied characters, look them up and add it to "myarray"

Comment: Worked like magic, Federico. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a bunch!